# Mac hangs indefinitely at shutdown

Tags: macos, kernel

When I reboot my mac running Yosemite, all the applications will quit, the desktop icons disappear, but then the computer hangs indefinitely. The desktop background and dock are still visible and the dock is still responsive to the mouse and to right clicks. I had the issue about a month ago and almost asked this question, but it spontaneously resolved itself.

I'm including my system.log in case that's useful. Please let me know if there is there a different log file that would be more informative.

Many thanks for any insights.

I attempt to shutdown at 10:12, then let the computer sit until 10:22. Here's a excerpt of the system.log during the hang

> Jun 19 10:10:10 daelab mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7f83b98dc000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/firmwaresyncd.5QZ5zf
>
> Jun 19 10:10:22 daelab SystemUIServer[319]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
>
> Jun 19 10:10:39 daelab mdworker[490]: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldnât be completed. (OSStatus error -67062.)"
>
> Jun 19 10:11:13 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: GetSettings File: ../../vpn/Agent/ServicePluginMgr.cpp Line: 274 m_pIServicePlugin is NULL
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: HandleError File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HttpSession_curl.cpp Line: 705 Invoked Function: CHttpSessionCurl::HandleError Return Code: 52 (0x00000034) Description: unknown
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: SendRequest File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HttpSession_curl.cpp Line: 943 curl_easy_perform error - 52 Error
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: SendHttpRequest File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/FileUploader.cpp Line: 197 Invoked Function: HttpSession::SendRequest Return Code: 52 (0x00000034) Description: unknown
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: PostDataGetResponse File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/FileUploader.cpp Line: 417 Invoked Function: CFileUploader::SendHttpRequest Return Code: -29032420 (0xFE45001C) Description: HTTP_SESSION_ERROR_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: PostDataFile File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/PhoneHomeAgent.cpp Line: 1650 Invoked Function: CFileUploader::PostDataGetResponse Return Code: -29032420 (0xFE45001C) Description: HTTP_SESSION_ERROR_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE Failed to post customer experence feedback data (/opt/cisco/anyconnect/CustomerExperienceFeedback/outbound/feedback_data2.cef)
>
> Jun 19 10:11:24 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: ScanAndPostFile File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/PhoneHomeAgent.cpp Line: 2340 post failed, give up this time.
>
> Jun 19 10:11:36 daelab mdworker[489]: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldnât be completed. (OSStatus error -67062.)"
>
> Jun 19 10:12:08 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
>
> Jun 19 10:12:08 daelab warmd[56]: [_bootcachectl_playlist_for_file:3202] Unable to generate playlist for file: 2 No such file or directory
>
> Jun 19 10:12:10 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
>
> Jun 19 10:12:10 daelab pkd[345]: ignoring mis-configured plug-in at /Applications/DEVONthink Pro.app/Contents/PlugIns/DEVONthink.appex: plug-ins must be sandboxed
>
> Jun 19 10:12:10 daelab mds[57]: (Server.Warning:445) No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
>
> Jun 19 10:12:11 daelab com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[499]: Layout still needs update after calling -[NSSavePanelAlertStyleContentView layout].  NSSavePanelAlertStyleContentView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.
>
> Jun 19 10:12:17 daelab CoreServicesUIAgent[390]: unexpected message  { count = 1, contents =
>
> "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
>
> }>
>
> Jun 19 10:12:17 daelab com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[499]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
>
> Jun 19 10:12:18 daelab loginwindow[94]: ERROR | __34-[SessionLogoutManager quitFinder]_block_invoke | Finder is killable, calling SMJobRemove
>
> Jun 19 10:12:18 daelab WindowServer[157]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 68879
>
> Jun 19 10:12:48 --- last message repeated 10 times ---
>
> Jun 19 10:14:35 daelab lsuseractivityd[362]: application (null) considered for activity continuation, but rejected because it will not run using a suitable architecture
>
> Jun 19 10:14:44 daelab lsuseractivityd[362]: application (null) considered for activity continuation, but rejected because it will not run using a suitable architecture
>
> Jun 19 10:15:34 daelab lsuseractivityd[362]: application (null) considered for activity continuation, but rejected because it will not run using a suitable architecture
>
> Jun 19 10:16:13 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
>
> Jun 19 10:16:13 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: CreateThreatReportDirChangeEvent File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/PhoneHomeAgent.cpp Line: 739 Failed to get threat directory information from settings
>
> Jun 19 10:16:13 daelab acvpnagent[45]: Function: OnTimerExpired File: ../../vpn/PhoneHome/PhoneHomeAgent.cpp Line: 1091 Failed to create threat report dir change event
>
> Jun 19 10:17:43 daelab bird[366]: Invalid signature for bookmark at path:'/Users/daeda/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Pages/Documents/Lab/Professional Log.pages' parentFileID:2059260 fileID:4378780 size:436384 mtime:1432310477 mode:-rw-r--r-- alias generationID:4 fd:18 refs:1
>
> Jun 19 10:17:43 daelab kernel[0]: bird[366] Unable to quarantine: 93
>
> Jun 19 10:17:43 daelab bird[366]: setting error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=6881396 "The operation couldnât be completed. (POSIX error 6881396 - Unknown error: 6881396)" UserInfo=0x7fa4d3d0f310 {NSDescription=Unknown error: 6881396}
>
> Jun 19 10:17:43 daelab bird[366]: Failed to unstage r:290 i:com.apple.Pages:00000000-0000-3000-000E-00000000252D up:idle st{p:00000000-0000-3000-0012-00000000022F n:"Professional Log.pages" fault reserved etag:j4 bt:1410301612 m:rw- doc:176 s_ino:2492196 s_gen:41} ct{etag:25 mt:1410301612 sz:444 KB (454540) n:"Professional Log.pages" sig:01481ac895dff04a9939c7dbc5d891a1e94bd4b6a6 device:1} downloading [(null)] to Professional Log.pages: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=6881396 "The operation couldnât be completed. (POSIX error 6881396 - Unknown error: 6881396)" UserInfo=0x7fa4d3d0f310 {NSDescription=Unknown error: 6881396}
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab bird[366]: Invalid signature for bookmark at path:'/Users/daeda/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Pages/Documents/Lab/Lab Notebook 1 Brewer.pages' parentFileID:2059260 fileID:4378778 size:1376928 mtime:1432310476 mode:-rw-r--r-- alias generationID:4 fd:18 refs:1
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab kernel[0]: bird[366] Unable to quarantine: 93
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab bird[366]: setting error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-729391104 "The operation couldnât be completed. (POSIX error -729391104 - Unknown error: -729391104)" UserInfo=0x7fa4d3d278d0 {NSDescription=Unknown error: -729391104}
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab bird[366]: Failed to unstage r:289 i:com.apple.Pages:00000000-0000-3000-000E-0000000006FA up:idle st{p:00000000-0000-3000-0012-00000000022F n:"Lab Notebook 1 Brewer.pages" fault reserved etag:im bt:1412206929 m:rw- doc:175 s_ino:2492194 s_gen:58} ct{etag:27 mt:1412206929 sz:608 KB (622928) n:"Lab Notebook 1 Brewer.pages" sig:01316a18c5faf12326f95cfbdbf52efc91e63791a7 device:1} downloading [(null)] to Lab Notebook 1 Brewer.pages: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-729391104 "The operation couldnât be completed. (POSIX error -729391104 - Unknown error: -729391104)" UserInfo=0x7fa4d3d278d0 {NSDescription=Unknown error: -729391104}
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab bird[366]: Invalid signature for bookmark at path:'/Users/daeda/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Pages/Documents/Practice/Practice Journal.pages' parentFileID:2059416 fileID:2059450 size:1385784 mtime:1433460640 mode:-rw-r--r-- alias generationID:14 fd:18 refs:1
>
> Jun 19 10:17:44 daelab kernel[0]: bird[366] Unable to quarantine: 93

Answer (score 1):

Enable verbose boot mode, which also enables verbose shutdown mode:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
```

(must reboot for that to take effect)

Then watch what's printed to the screen on the next shutdown. Maybe take a picture with your phone.

You can also see all messages that got logged, no matter whether they made it to the syslog file or any other flat text logfile, by running the `syslog` command. It'll spew a lot of log messages. Scroll back until you find the previous shutdown, and copy all those lines.

Tip: Edit/Update your Question with that information. Wrap the text block in <pre></pre> tags to make it format right.

P.S. If you later decide you don't like verbose booting, you can go back to normal with:

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my Early 2011 MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and was able to resolve the problem by deleting `~/Library//Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`.
I also deleted the `~/Library//Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState` folder, but I don't think that was necessary.